# Avoid duplicates while adding in dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary in which I'm adding values like so...

```
var mydictionary = ["id": "", "quantity": "","sellingPrice":""] as [String : Any]
    dictionary["id"] = product?.id
    dictionary["quantity"] = product?.quantity
    dictionary["sellingPrice"] = product?.theRate
```

And these values I added to an array like so...

```
self.arrayOfDictionary.append(mydictionary)
```

But if `arrayOfDictionary` already contains `mydictionary`, I don't want to add it. Else, I want to add it.

The basic idea here is to add data from collection view items to array of dictionary. When I click on the buttons that I have on each collection view item the data on it is added to an array of dict. while at the same time showing those data in a tableviewcell. But when I navigate back from the tableview & visit the collectionview items again and click on some other collecn.view item, so as to add them to the array of dictionary as before, then the item that was added initially to the array of dictionary gets added again. This has to be somehow prevented.

As suggested by another SO user something like this was tried to prevent this duplication...

```
    if self.arrayOfDictionary.contains(where: { (dict) -> Bool in
        "\(dict["id"] ?? "")" != "\(dictionary["id"] ?? "")"}) {
        self.arrayOfDictionary.append(dictionary)
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work. With this nothing is added to the array and its totally empty. Hope somebody can help...

Comment: Why don't you disable button in CollectionView item by comparing existing array of dictionary with displaying one. That'll be easier then comparing array every time.

Comment: maybe I didn't get you, @DipakKacha. I don't have an existing array of dictionary. When I click on the btn, it is then that I want to add to the array of dictionary...

Comment: you can try like

if self.arrayOfDictionary( { $0.id == dictionary.id } ) == false {

        self.arrayOfDictionary.append(dictionary)

    print("Object Added")

} else {

    print("Object already exists")

 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to avoid duplication

I hope "id" value will be unique in your dictionary.

```
    var mydictionary = ["id": "1", "quantity": "","sellingPrice":""] as [String : Any]

    var arrayOfDictionary = [Dictionary<String, Any>]() //declare this globally
    let arrValue = arrayOfDictionary.filter{ (($0["id"]!) as! String).range(of: mydictionary["id"]! as! String, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil }
    if arrValue.count == 0 {

        arrayOfDictionary.append(mydictionary)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks...Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got better idea then every time you perform loop to check unique ness.

Maintain one Bool array of same size of your collectionView Items array with predefined false values each.

When you click on button of collection View item, change flag of Bool array with same index. And simultaneously you can disable the button also(if you want). Otherwise whenever user clicks on button, just check flag from Bool array and add Dictionary to new array as needed.

Here, your new array will be performed and you will same process and time of looping also.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach the problem could be to construct a structure which contains product details:

```
/// Details Of A Product
struct ProductDetails{

var id: String!
var quantity: Int!
var sellingPrice: Int!

}
```

Then create a dictionary which stores the product details with the key being the "ID" e.g:

```
var products = [String: ProductDetails]()
```

You could then create a product like so:

```
let productA = ProductDetails(id: "1", quantity: 100, sellingPrice: 10)
```

To add a unique product to your dictionary you could use a function like this:

```
/// Adds A Product To The Products Dictionary
///
/// - Parameter product: ProductDetails
func addProductDetails(_ product: ProductDetails){

    //1. If A Product Exists Ignore It
    if products[product.id] != nil{
        print("Product With ID \(product.id!) Already Exists")
    }else{
        //2. It Doesn't Exist So Add It To The Dictionary
        products[product.id] = product
    }
}
```

I tested this quickly and it won't allow products which have duplicate ID's. although of course you could change the parameter as needed.

Comment: Did try @Josh Robbins..but it doesn't seems to work in my case...:(

Comment: From what I understand therefore, is that when you move to another ViewController. that your 'product' dictionary is essential removed from memory and thus becomes empty. As such you probably need to look at a way to store the array in memory. A dirty way to do this for example could be to store it in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: if this is tried `let arrValue = self.appDelegate.arrayOfDictionary.filter{ (($0["id"]!) as! String).range(of: dictionary["id"]! as! String, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil }`, I get a json value in it. Now how can I check if my array contains this `json` value or not? I that can be achieved the problem can hopefully be fixed...